# Need to find even sums of digits in the array

Tags: java

I need to find even sum of digits from an array in Java.

```
Array: int [] cars = {3, 4, 6, 5};
```

> Output: 8 10
>
> Process:
>
> 3 + 4 == 7 --> not even
>
> 3 + 6 == 9 --> not even
>
> 3 + 5 == 8 --> even (so print it)

> 4 + 6 == 10 --> even (so print it)
>
> 4 + 5 == 9 --> not even

> 6 + 5 == 11 --> not even

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of terms?

Comment: You are expected to write code yourself. If you have a problem that you can't solve by debugging or reading documentation, then post that code here with a clear problem statement.

See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) regarding asking homework questions.

Comment: This is not a homework question :) I made it myself and can't find a solution

Comment: @jjavid Are you just looking for all pairs in the array with an even sum?

Comment: Even if it's not a homework question, you need to show a good-faith attempt to solve the problem. Do you have any idea how to approach it?

Comment: Update, i guess i solved it. Thanks to everyone!!!!!                                                                         


`public class main
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {      
     int [] cars = {3, 4, 5, 6};
     
     for(int i=0; i<cars.length; i++)
     { 
      for(int j=0; j<cars.length; j++)
      {
       if(cars[i] != cars[j])
       {
        if((cars[i] + cars[j]) % 2 == 0) 
        System.out.println(cars[i] + cars[j]);
       }
      }
     }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is to check two value combination, you can use something like the below,

```
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("" + arr[i] + "+" + arr[j] + "=even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("" + arr[i] + "+" + arr[j] + "=odd");
            }
        }
    }
```

and the output will look like this

```
1+2=odd
1+3=even
1+4=odd
1+5=even
1+6=odd
2+3=odd
2+4=even
2+5=odd
2+6=even
3+4=odd
3+5=even
3+6=odd
4+5=odd
4+6=even
5+6=odd
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much! i'm new to stackoverflow, so i didn't see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

filter the array into two lists, one for odd numbers and another for even numbers, then loop over each list summing each element with all the others and checking the results, at the end of the loop, remove that element.
the benefit of filtering the array to odd and even numbers is that odd + even is always odd, so, eliminating this case saves you some time.

Comment: Solved it like this :-)                                                                                                    

public class main
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {      
     int [] cars = {3, 4, 5, 6};
     
     for(int i=0; i<cars.length; i++)
     { 
      for(int j=0; j<cars.length; j++)
      {
       if(cars[i] != cars[j])
       {
        if((cars[i] + cars[j]) % 2 == 0) 
        System.out.println(cars[i] + cars[j]);
       }
      }
     }
    }
}